# Running Several asynctask in my MainActivity

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask

I'm displaying 5 large Bitmaps in my MainActivity following this Google instructions to avoid memory leaks and not freeze the UI Thread.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

So, I'm starting one `Asynctask` for each one of my 5 large Bitmaps in the `onCreate` method...

I'm not freezing the UI thread (good) because I'm running my long processes in one thread each one but "my problem" is that these 5 large Bitmaps are part of the same figure (face) and when the app starts the user can see how the different layers are being loaded at different time.

I've thought in a splash screen until my images are loaded but I'd like to know if this is the best way to do that (because the splash is needed maybe less than 1 second) or there is a better way, like notify the UI thread when the last image is loaded and then show all the images...or maybe try to load all the images in the same `Asynctask`?

Thanks in advance,

Paola.

Comment: you have to provide a progress until loading. See this API it is really simple to use:  https://github.com/androidquery/androidquery

Comment: I am assuming that, naturally, you would be displaying the Bitmap that you download in each individual `AsyncTask` in their respective `onPostExecute()`. Why not call the next the `AsyncTask` in each `onPostExecute()` saving the Bitmap and showing them in the final `AsyncTask`? This way, the Bitmaps will be visible in one go. This is just at the top of my mind. I do this in an app where I get the data for a _"Header"_, then load the _"Comments"_ and show them together in the `AsyncTask` for _"Comments"_.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've loaded the 5 large Bitmaps in the same Asynctask. I've loaded them in doInBackground method and display all of them at once in the onPostExecute of my ASynctask.

I was thinking about Siddharth Lele's answer and I wanted something like that but I understood that you got the same result calling one Asynctask from the onPostExecute of the other Asynctask and waiting to the last Asynctask to display the ImageViews that doing it in the doInBackground method the only one Asynctask and waiting to the postExecute of this Asynctask until all the Bitmaps were loaded, and I think it's more efficient because you have not more threads that what you need...

Let me know if there is some other consideration with this approach.

Thanks!

Comment: just don't forget to cancel the task when needed , and to set a timeout in case the server (or connection ) has problems. you might also check for the connectivity before even starting the asyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Android, there is a dequeue in front of the AsyncTask executor thread pool.  It only allows one task to run at a time.  That means that your tasks happen in order, which is usually what you expect.  In a case like this, though, it means that you are *not* simultaneously loading all 5 images.  Have a look at:

```
executeOnExecutor(Executor exec, Params... params)
```

... which allows you to bypass the dequeue.  That will get you concurrency.

Network connections from AsyncTasks seem dubious to me.  What if one of them fails?  A better solution to this problem might be a multi-threaded, bound service, that did a callback when all 5 images had been downloaded.

Comment: Only for the records I'm not downloading the bitmaps from the network. Only decoding that from resources with some options like the Android guide explains here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html